# backup servers for domain

Tags: domain-name-system, backup

I have domain example.com and I have site hosted on two servers serverip1 and serverip2

I want serpverip1 be the default server and if anything goes wrong then example.com should direct all requests to serverip2 (like I want serverip2 to be my backup server)

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

**This cannot be done with DNS.** If you're thinking that you've heard something like this being done, you might be confusing Round Robin DNS with some form of redundancy or failover. Round robin DNS will distribute a different IP address to a DNS client requesting name resolution.

To do anything like this with DNS, from a theoretical standpoint, you'd need to switch your `example.com` domain A records from the failed node, to point to the standby node. You'd want your TTL values on the A record to be very low so that most DNS client won't have an old, stale record. However this is assuming that DNS servers across the globe that cache your record will always honor TTL values, which is not the case.

To make your two servers be able to handle a failure event, you will need a hardware load balancer in front of the two servers to intelligently determine when one of the two web servers is non responsive and then have all traffic forwarded to the secondary one. The DNS A record will point to the load balancer, and the load balancer will then distribute traffic in the manner that you desire to the servers behind it.

Comment: And if you are concerned with making things redundant you probably want a PAIR of load balancers in case one of those dies too!

Comment: ...and then a pair of drops to each load balancer. And a pair of geo-diverse datacenters. And a pair of alternate universes...

Comment: Yep.  And redundant power, generaters, routers, switches, etc.  Remember murphys law tells you the item you didnt make redundant will probably fail first! Just keep adding everything in pairs until you go 'aw @#$% it, if that fails I'm just gonna give up'